# DLL load time in Chrome vs IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

For varies reasons, I have a DLL with 27k items.  It is a near instantaneous load in Chrome, but takes 10 seconds in IE.  Does anyone know why?

I'm using the MVC.HTML.SelectExtensions DLL.

Comment: Maybe because IE is known as the slowest browser ?

Comment: Which version of IE specifically?

Comment: -Update- IE9 works fine, while IE11 has issues.  I was checking browser compatibility using the IE11 developer tools, which seems to load different than than the actual product.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your system, I suspect you may be hit by ***virus scan***.

I have seen >10x slowdowns processing java-script heavy HTML (at my client at the time). The thing was that McAfee replaces the JavaScript script host with it's own version, for security checks.

> **[Background information](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2007/11/03/quickpost-scanning-scripts/)**
>   (this page appears to suggest that other AV programs have similar mechanisms)

Disabling that **[1]** fixed the performance. I think there should be a way to exclude certain sites (e.g. intranet) from these mechanisms. Don't remember whether they've found it.

---

**[1]** If you know what you're doing (both technically and security-wise) you can google for many places that tell you how to run `regsvr32 jscript.dll` on the original Microsoft script engine.

Comment: Because IE is the only one that uses Microsoft's script engines. Chrome and Firefox use their own java script implementations (V8 and SpiderMonkey, respectively)

Comment: That is an interesting possibility. I will look into that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the cause.  My best guess at this time, is that the default MVC Dropdown has issues with the newer versions of IE?